# How to display user control within the main window in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application and just embarked in learning MVVM pattern.

My goal is that in my application the main window has a button. When this button is clicked, another window (or user control) will appear on top of the main window.

This is the code of MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SmartPole1080.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core.Utilities;assembly=SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core"
    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:SoltaLabs.Avalon.View.Core.UserControls;assembly=SoltaLabs.Avalon.View.Core"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfKb.Controls;assembly=SmartPole.WpfKb"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WebEye.Controls.Wpf;assembly=WebEye.Controls.Wpf.WebCameraControl"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SmartPole.View;assembly=SmartPole.View"
    xmlns:view1="clr-namespace:SmartPole1080.View"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core.Behaviors;assembly=SoltaLabs.Avalon.Core"
    Title="Smart Pole" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Name="mainWindow"
    behaviors:IdleBehavior.IsAutoReset="True" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
<Canvas Background="DarkGray">
    <!--Main Grid-->
    <Grid Width="1080" Height="1920" Background="White" Name="MainGrid"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Background="Black">                
            <Grid Background="#253341">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="264"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button Tag="{StaticResource EmergencyImg}" Name="EmergencyButton"
                            Command="{Binding ShowEmergencyPanel}">
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource EmergencyImg}" />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

                <!--Emergency Window Dialog-->
                <Grid Name="EmergencyPanel">
                    <view1:EmergencyInfo x:Name="EmergencyInfoPanel"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <!--Main Grid-->
</Canvas>
```

This is the other window (user control - EmergencyInfo.xaml)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartPole1080.View.EmergencyInfo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartPole1080.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1920" d:DesignWidth="1050"
         x:Name="EmergencyInfoPanel">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="White" Background="White">
        <Button Background="White" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="25" Margin="0,0,15,0"
                Command="{Binding HideEmergencyPanel}">
            close X
        </Button>
    </Border>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{StaticResource EdenParkInfoImg}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

I want to implement this behavior using an MVVM pattern.  I have set the binding `ShowEmergencyPanel` in button EmergencyButton to show EmergencyInfo when this button is click.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's type of `EmergencyImg`?

Comment: @LeiYang the type of `EmergencyImg` is a BitmapImage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why dont you make navigation, something like this. Make section for conetent that will be injected, and whatever type of object you are expecting put it in Windows.Resources in DataTemplate.

In main windo xaml

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type home:HomeViewModel}">
            <home:HomeView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type other:OtherViewModel}">
            <other:OtherView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="Navigation">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="HomeView"
                        Content="Home"
                        Margin="5"
                        Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="home" />
                <Button x:Name="Menu"
                        Content="OtherView"
                        Margin="5"
                        Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="Other" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="MainContent"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel can look something like this.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private OtherViewModel otherVM;
        private HomeViewModel homeVM;

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigationCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            otherVM = new OtherViewModel();
            homeVM = new HomeViewModel();

            // Setting default: homeViewModela.
            CurrentViewModel = homeVM;

            NavigationCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNavigate);
        }

        private void OnNavigate(string navPath)
        {
            switch (navPath)
            {
                case "other":
                    CurrentViewModel = otherVM;
                    break;
                case "home":
                    CurrentViewModel = homeVM;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private object _currentViewModel;
        public object CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return _currentViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentViewModel != value)
                {
                    _currentViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
          PropertyChanged(this, new propertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Where DelegateCommand you can make yours,check how to make RelayCommand(and generic one) or use PRISM that have it's own DelegateCommand. But if you want to use PRISM, it allready has navigation to regions, that can solve many problems. Check videos from Brian Lagunas.

**EDIT:**
This is to show/hide grid. In your mainWindow where you set that EmergencyInfo u can show/hide that grid this way.

in your MainViewViewModel make a bool property IsVisible

```
private bool _isVisible;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return _isVisible; }
            set
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

in your MainView.Resources set key to BooleanToVisibilityConverter
something like:

```
 <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Show"/>
```

and your grid that you want to show/hide set visibility:

```
<Grid x:Name="SomeGridName"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Colum="1"
              Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource Show}}">
```

And finally set that IsVisible property to some ToggleButton, just to switch between true/false

```
 <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}"
                              Content="ShowGrid" />
```

This way, you show/hide that grid part based on IsVisible, and you control that visibility onClick. Hope that helps.

Comment: Navigation is a good idea, however the application that I'm working on doesn't need to have a navigation because it is being displayed in a 1080 x 1920 screen dimension.

Comment: I have provide you some basic insight on how to toggle between show/hide some part of your window. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I tried what you have suggested.  Unfortunately, still the EmergencyInfo panel did not show up.  I did create a ToggleButton in `MainWindow.xaml` and wired up its click event handler that set the panel visibility.  In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, the `EmergencyButton_Click`  event calls a public method `SetPanelVisibility` that takes a boolean value as parameter.  This method is declared inside my `MainViewModel` where `IsEmergencyPanelVisibile` property on changed is also been set.  But, still the `EmergencyInfo.xaml` user control doesn't show.  What could have been wrong?

Comment: U didn't have to make any click events on ToggleButton, just like in example Bind ToggleButton IsChecked to IsVisible property. Important is that your IsVisible property is on your DataContext ViewModel, and that is implements INotifyPropertyChanged or your UI wont be notified. U dont have to make any code behinde in that solution that i have provided. That up is a simple solution, and i have tried it and it works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm confused about your statement "This way, you show/hide that grid part based on IsVisible, and you control that visibility onClick."  How do I switch IsVisible property to true/false if I'm not going to bind ToggleButton to click event?

Comment: When you use ToggleButton, each click will change IsVisible property( that property is on your DataContext), and that's why you don't have to make events, and becouse IsVisible is using OnPropertyChange() then every click will change state of visibility of that part of grid. Try some simple solution , just to hide/ show grid as in the solution, then you can implement that on bigger scale. Imagine ToggleButton as CheckBox when using IsClicked, then ea click will change it's state.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your Window xaml:

```
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Control}"></ContentPresenter>
```

In this way, your ViewModel must contain a Control property.

Add your ViewModel to DataContext of Window. 
(For example in window constructor, `this.Datacontext = new ViewModel();`)

Or another way with interfaces:

```
 public interface IWindowView
 {
        IUserControlKeeper ViewModel { get; set; }
 }

 public interface IUserControlKeeper 
 {
        UserControl Control { get; set; }
 }


 public partial class YourWindow : IViewWindow
 {
        public YourWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IUserControlKeeper ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (IUserControlKeeper)DataContext;
            }

            set
            {
                DataContext = value;
            }
        }
  }
```

(In this way, initialize your window where you want to use. Service?)

```
private IViewWindow _window;
private IViewWindow Window  //or public...
{
  get{
       if(_window==null)
       {
           _window = new YourWindow();
           _window.ViewModel = new YourViewModel();
       }
       return _window;
     }
}
```

Open your window with one of your UserControls:

```
  void ShowWindowWithControl(object ControlView, INotifyPropertyChanged ControlViewModel, bool ShowAsDialog)
  {
        if(ControlView is UserControl)
        {       //with interface: Window.ViewModel.Control = ...
               (Window.DataContext as YourViewModel).Control = (UserControl)ControlView;

               if (ControlViewModel != null)
                   (Window.DataContext as YourViewModel).Control.DataContext = ControlViewModel;

               if (ShowAsDialog) //with interface use cast to call the show...
                   Window.ShowDialog();
               else
                   Window.Show();

         }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, place the Emergency usercontrol inside MainGrid and control its visibility through Model property.

```
    <Canvas Background="DarkGray">
    <!--Main Grid-->
    <Grid Width="1080" Height="1920" Background="White" Name="MainGrid"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Background="Black">                
            <Grid Background="#253341">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="264"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button Tag="{StaticResource EmergencyImg}" Name="EmergencyButton"
                            Command="{Binding ShowEmergencyPanel}">
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource EmergencyImg}" />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>


            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Name="EmergencyPanel">
            <view1:EmergencyInfo x:Name="EmergencyInfoPanel" Visibility={Binding IsEmergencyPanelVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}} DataContext={Binding} />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <!--Main Grid-->
</Canvas>
```

By setting proper background to Grid that holding usercontrol, you can achieve modal window like effect.
And you need to have IsEmergencyPanelVisible(default value is false) is your Model, and this property should be changed to true on your button click command.

Note : I guess you are familiar with converters, so i included Converters in my solution.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the `EmergencyInfo` view didn't show when `IsEmergencyPanelVisible` is set to true. I have a `MainViewModel` class, and in the constructor `EmergencyCommand` is initialize. Something like this,`EmergencyCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => _window.ToggleEmergency());` which _window is of type `IMainWindow` that implements `ToggleEmergency`. And in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, `ToggleEmergency` is invoked like this `_mainVm.EmergencyInfoViewModel.IsEmergencyPanelVisible = true;`  Would you know what could have been missing?

Comment: @Juniuz you're sure that, only one datacontext exists? _mainVm is the datacontext for usercontrol also? and have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I have a bunch of `DataContext`, which EmergencyInfo view has its own view model `EmergencyInfoViewModel`.  The variable `_mainVm` is of type `MainViewModel`, which is initialize in MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor and includes a number of other view models used in the application.   The `INotifyPropertyChanged` is already been implemented via an `ObservableObject` which takes a generic of type T.  And, `_mainVm` is not the datacontext of the user control (EmergencyInfo.xaml).  Did I miss something very important in terms of binding?

Comment: @Juniuz No, everything is correct.. I'm guessing there may be more than one instance of MainViewModel and when we set true to IsEmergencyPanelVisible, it setting the value to wrong instance. Put a breakpoint in IsEmergencyPanelVisible get and set and check for the values, when we set true. and also i've modified the code littlebit. try that also.