# WPF Application (Binding and navigation)

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am developing my first WPF application and I am having trouble with binding and navigation. What I want to do is to create a UI in which there are a right and top panel which are used to navigate between the frame and the remaining space in the window is used to display the different frames.
I think that the best practice would be to use different viewmodels each one associated to a different xaml and bind the viewmodels to the area in which I want the content to be displayed. Anyway my questions are:
1) Which UI component should I use to display the changing content in the main Window? A Page? A UserControl?
2) How can I make the binding?
3) Is there some guide or article that is not msdn that you suggest me to read?

Comment: Here is allready answered how to make a simple navigation, i think it can set you on right track. [simple navigation in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709379/how-to-display-user-control-within-the-main-window-in-wpf-using-mvvm/42714915#42714915)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I do to handle communication and navigation between Views and ViewModels is that I have a Base-ViewModel that all my other ViewModels inherit and a "Shell-View" that displays my Main-Window.

Then I just use whatever Base-ViewModel that comes in into my Shell-View datacontext.

I use `UserControl` for and then put it into `ContentControl`s.

[Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation)

[Here is a good tutorial for MVVM Navigation](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

I highly suggest that you go through this blog, cause it explains really well on how MVVM **CAN** be used.